# Is it possible to filter the attribute table in several years at the same time?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, filter, qgsexpression

I have a very extensive attribute table (see screenshot) and would now like to filter the objects according to certain years (1997, 2002, 2009, 2014 and 2018) and, after that, biotope types. I think that I could formulate it using expressions, but I cannot find a formulation for a list. Maybe it is not possible?

[image]

Comment: You should provide us the structure of you attribute table to see how it looks, where you have the years etc. Add a screenshot to your question.

Comment: Please also [Edit] the question to specify the format/source of the data. "Very extensive" tables ought to be in a RDBMS.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot. At first, I would like to filter according to "DATUM_E"

Comment: @ Vince with very extensive I mean that I have more than 25000 Objects (just polygones in one shape file)  in my attribute table

Comment: Why not do a query via layer properties?

Answer (score 6):

Use `Advanced Filter (Expression)` at the bottom left of the attribute table. To get all dates of 2018, use this expression: `"DATUM_E" >= '2018-01-01' and "DATUM_E" <= '2018-12-31'` or easier: `year("DATUM_E") = 2018`.

To seelct several years at once, use `year("DATUM_E") in (2018, 2014, 2009, 2002, 1997)`.

You can now add different conditions and connect them with `and`, `or`, `not`, `like` etc ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#operators)). Such a combines expression for all dates of 2018, 2014, 2009, 2002 and 1997, where "BIOTYP_T" > 08000 could look like this:

```
(year("DATUM_E") in (2018, 2014, 2009, 2002, 1997)) and "BIOTYP_T" > 08000
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great! :)

Comment: You're welcome. As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235